# Which site to ask a question about using Infogram?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've done an internet search for "stack exchange infogram" but I didn't see a site where questions about using Infogram would be clearly on topic.

I want to create an Infogram chart and link a Google sheet document to it. I've found instructions, but I get different results from what's expected no matter how many times I try, and I can't progress.

I'm not sure if this is a Super User question, or a data question, or something else. Which site would be best to ask my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infogram)

> Infogram is a web-based data visualization and infographics platform

<sub>as an aside, I initially confused infogram with infogrames, an old game publisher</sub>

Since google sheets is also web based

[Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) seems the right site